# DHCP client fails to get IP address (Modem EM7430)

Tags: debian, modem, dhclient

O/S: Raspberry Pi running Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

Kernel: Linux 4.9.24-v7+

Ran ***ip addr*** and confirmed **wwan0** and **wwan1** interfaces are created.

```
wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether ce:d3:4d:fc:a7:9b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 169.254.160.49/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global wwan0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

wwan1: .....
```

Successfully started

```
qmi-network /dev/cdc-wdm0 start
```

Ran

```
qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --wda-get-data-format
```

and got result

```
                        QoS flow header: no
                    Link layer protocol: 'raw-ip'
       Uplink data aggregation protocol: 'disabled'
     Downlink data aggregation protocol: 'disabled'
                          NDP signature: '0'
Downlink data aggregation max datagrams: '0'
     Downlink data aggregation max size: '0'
```

Ran

```
qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --nas-get-signal-strength
```

and got result

```
Current:
     Network 'umts': '-103 dBm'
RSSI:
     Network 'umts': '-103 dBm'
ECIO:
     Network 'umts': -10.0 dBm'
IO: '-106 dBm'
SINR: (8) '9.0 dB'
```

Ran

```
dhclient -v wwan0
```

and got result

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.1
...

Listening on LPF/wwan0/ce:d3:4d:fc:a7:9b
Sending on   LPF/wwan0/ce:d3:4d:fc:a7:9b
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
DHCPDISCOVER on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
....
....
```

I tried a lot of times and still cannot get the IP address.

Any help is appreciated.

---

Edited:

Also, I have tried to change the link layer protocol to 802-3

```
qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --wda-set-data-format=802-3
```

The message said 'Successfully set data format', but the link layer protocol still is 'raw-ip'.

Comment: Run `dhcpcd` command

Comment: Installed dhcpcd and ran dhcpcd wwan0.  Still cannot get the IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help.

I found out that the EM7430 does not support 802-3 and is raw ip only.  It does not work with dhclient nor dhcpcd.

Comment: This is true of the Sierra Wireless EM/MC74 and EM75 series modules, Telit LM940 and LN940 series, and probably others. Looks like `wvdial` is a path of less resistance than `udhcpc` for me.

Answer (score 1):

`dhclient` and `dhcpcd` don't seem to have support for raw-ip. I did however manage to get an IP with `udhcpc`. It's not available on all Linux distros though, so you're limited to Debian based distros.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't the problem be with the server? Did you try other devices/PCs to make sure they are getting an IP or not? The problem could possibly be with the DHCP server for some reason.
Make also sure you are not using a static IP configured on the interface. (I can see you are getting an APIPA address but what is the config in the wwan0.conf for example?

Comment: I can use dhcp to get IP address for my eth0 device.  So, it is working fine.  I suspect the EM7430 is raw-ip only and dhcp will not work.  I need to confirm this.